# Unity Failed to create decoder for ScreenSelector.png

Tags: unity

My game works fine in the editor, but when I build and run the build the view is zoomed in, my tilemap is missing, and the camera follows a gameobject it should not.

[How it should look and how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USwlk.jpg)

I checked the logs and this is the error I am served:

> Failed to create decoder for 'C:/Users/Hamuel The First/Documents/Jetplatformer/Builds/Builds_Data/ScreenSelector.png': 0x80070002

Further Investigation shows that ScreenSelector.png is absent from the path stated in the error. I cannot find anything that says what ScreenSelector.png is, or does. I am using the post processing stack by unity.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are on the beta channel. This looks like a known bug.

More details can be found here
https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/deployment-management-failed-to-create-decoder-exception-thrown-while-playing-development-build

This doesn't actually cause anything that I can tell and the game runs. Are you sure this is not a red herring?